# How to perform simple arithmetic with page number?

Tags: page-numbering, counters

I want to play around the Latex variable `\thepage`. How to do that? For example subtract 1 from the current page:

```
\thepage-1
```

Comment: `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` is probably what you are searching for.

Comment: I've tried it but nothing displays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options.

If you want to globally change the page number, you can use `\addtocounter` or `\setcounter`, as recommended by Thorsten Donig.

If you want to use the result in a length or counter, as in `\setcounter`, `\addtocounter`, `\setlength`, or `\addtolength`, you can use the [`calc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) package. For example, one less than the page number is `\setcounter{pagelessone}{\thepage-1}`, where `pagelessone` is some counter you've already defined.

If you want to do something more complicated, you can use the [eTeX](http://ctan.org/pkg/etex/) primitives `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr`. For example, one less than the page number is `\numexpr\thepage-1\relax`. For more information, see section 3.5 of the [eTeX documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/e-tex/v2/doc/etex_man.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *advance* command:

```
\advance\thepage -1
```